# Disable @media in css

Tags: css, css-selectors, media-queries

I have some set of CSS classes and in one of classes we track max width of sized window and change styles if it is less then 100.

```
@media all and (max-width: 100px) { 
   some code...
}
```

So I need to prevent changing styles when window is width is less than 100. In other words how I can overload current `@media` and disable it, only by CSS way (not javascript, jQuery)?

Comment: Can't you just remove this code?

Comment: nope, it is template which we use in different places.

Comment: Not with CSS only. You might be able to hack something together with JavaScript, but that would be atrocious to maintain.

Comment: This is clearly not the intent of your teacher... better bark up a different tree.

Comment: it's hard to believe that this code works: It should be `100px` instead of just `100`. Also, that could only apply to smart watches or similar devices - there are no smartphones narrower than 100px...

Comment: Yeah - I just debugged someone's code - and no `px` failed.

Comment: @Johannes You can change the size of a browser window.

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski first of all, that clearly isn't the purpose of a media query in the real world, second I can't make *any* browser window narrower than about 250px - just won't let me do it.

Comment: it is just example, put 300px then, no matter. Question is related to other thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to body (for example `.no-media`) and add styles for this class:

```
@media all and (max-width: 100) {
  .no-media p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

You can also use `!important` to force some CSS rules:

```
p {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: This media changes a lot of styles, so I need some simple solution just to disable it only by css way.

Comment: @Ted Can't you just not include that style sheet?

Comment: don't thing, it is in one CSS file with other classes.

Comment: @Ted Gee, then split it into two CSS files.

Comment: The only think which I can do, it is to fix it by CSS way

Comment: _"This media changes a lot of styles, so I need some simple solution just to disable it only by css way"_ - well then you will at least have to overwrite each property changed inside the media query using [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/unset) - and if you need broader backwards compatibility, then you will need to overwrite them with specific values.